# Position of UIScrollView after change in orientation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with an image inside it. This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    UIScrollView *imScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 96)];
    [imScrollView addSubview:imView];
    [imScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(530, 96)];
    [[self view] addSubview:imScrollView];
    [imView release];
    [imScrollView release];
}
```

This is what it looks like in portrait mode:
[image]

I want to know
1. How can I position the image exactly in the middle of the screen (horizontally).
2. How can I make sure this is going to be the same if the orientation switches to landscape. This is what currently the landscape looks like :
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `autoresizingMask` property of your `imView` just after you create it:

```
imView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

The `UIView` class reference contains more info.